# GNU findutils doesn't find file

Tags: linux, bash, find, gnu-findutils

When searching for .txt files that are in 2 different home directories only one shows up depending on the present working directory. Why is this?

```
/home/bob/1.txt 
/home/alice/dir1/2.txt

pwd /tmp
[root@host tmp]#find /home -name *.txt 
/home/bob/1.txt 
/home/alice/dir1/2.txt

pwd /home
[root@host bob]#find /home -name *.txt 
/home/bob/1.txt
```

Why does searching from within the bob directory only return the one file?

Comment: [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) detects this and other common problems, and says to "[Quote the parameter to -name](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2061) so the shell won't interpret it."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does searching from within the bob directory only return the one file?

Because when the working directory is `/home/bob`, the `*.txt` in the `find` command is expanded by the shell (to `1.txt`) and that is what is passed to `find`.  That is, `find /home -name 1.txt`.  That will find the file in `/home/bob`, but not the differently named one in `/home/alice`.  It *would* find `/home/alice/1.txt` if such a file existed.

On the other hand, when the pattern does not match any file (relative to the working directory) it is passed on as a literal.  At least by default -- you should be careful about this, because the pattern would instead be expanded to nothing if the `nullglob` shell option were in effect and the `find` command were executed from a location where the pattern didn't match any files.

If you want to ensure that shell pathname expansion is not applied to the pattern then quote it:

```
find /home -name '*.txt'
```

or

```
find /home -name \*.txt
```

or ....